# How do I unpack initrd of ubuntu 18.04 and then pack it back?

Tags: ubuntu-18.04

I used binwalk to unpack initrd of ubuntu 18.04
But it didnt unpack the package

```
command used #  sudo binwalk initrd
===========
result:
==========
DECIMAL         HEX             DESCRIPTION
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0               0x0             ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "."
112             0x70            ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel"
232             0xE8            ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel/x86"
356             0x164           ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel/x86/microcode"
488             0x1E8           ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel/x86/microcode/AuthenticAMD.bin"
28072           0x6DA8          ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "TRAILER!!!"
28672           0x7000          ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel"
28792           0x7078          ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel/x86"
28916           0x70F4          ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel/x86/microcode"
29048           0x7178          ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel/x86/microcode/.enuineIntel.align.0123456789abc"
29212           0x721C          ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "kernel/x86/microcode/GenuineIntel.bin"
2440880         0x253EB0        ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "TRAILER!!!"
===========
```

It gave nothing in destination folder

```
# file initrd 
initrd: ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC)
```

I tried extracting using cpio command,

```
build@###
:/source/build/1.0.5.00206/nm-gii/software/CD/build/initrd$ sudo cpio -i -F /source/build/1.0.5.00206/nm-gii/software/CD/build/extract-cd/casper/initrd
56 blocks
build@###:/source/build/1.0.5.00206/nm-gii/software/CD/build/initrd$ ll
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jan 15 05:36 ./
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jan 15 05:01 ../
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jan 15 05:36 kernel/
build@###:/source/build/1.0.5.00206/nm-gii/software/CD/build/initrd$
```

so all the files are still on extracted with this.

Comment: Do you want to just extract the files of the archive? Use [cpio](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-cpio/) to do it.

Comment: cpio isnt working to extract initrd

Comment: output using cpio
 sudo cpio -i -F  /source/build/1.0.5.00206/nm-gii/software/CD/build/extract-cd/casper/initrd
56 blocks
 ll
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jan 15 05:28 ./
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jan 15 05:01 ../
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jan 15 05:28 kernel/

Comment: The extracted file should be in the current directory. Otherwise try extracting again with the `--verbose` option. BTW, add the output of commands to the question, not comments, since the result is difficult to read.

Comment: Added the output of cpio to question.Please check

Comment: The initrd you are extracting is very small and you have its content in the `kernel` subdirectory.

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu, at least newer versions, you could use the commands `lsinitramfs <file>` to inspect and `unmkinitramfs <file> <target directory>` to extract.

Answer (score 1):

The initrd format can be a concatenation of stuff. Namely `cpio` archives and also could be a filesystem image. See [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/initrd.html).

**Option 1**

For `dracut` created initrds, to extract, you can use `lsinitrd --unpack` which comes with dracut.

**Option 2**

Another option is using the `skipcpio` tool also coming with dracut. See this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/279406/14907).

```
/usr/lib/dracut/skipcpio $your-initrd-img | zcat | cpio -id --no-absolute-file-names
```

**Option 3**

Another option is using `binwalk` and again cpio or whatever else is the initrd part. See this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192058/14907).

**Option 4** (probably what you were asking for)

But the best answer to traverse initrd, extracting and modifying is this:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/607996/14907

With it you can more easily extract only the parts you want to modify and then repack them the same way you unpacked. It is not a comprehensive guide but should give you most pieces if you are motivated.